# Button not clicking in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My question is the following in JavaScipt and HTML:

```
let submit = document.getElementById("button");
let text = document.getElementById("inputForm");
submit.addEventListener('сlick', function () {
   let textValue = text.value;
   console.log("The input is " + textValue)
});
```

I am sure I connected the HTML to JS correctly via the script attribute.

```
<div class="input">
    <h3 id="inputText">Ввод:</h3>
    <input id="inputForm" />
    <button id="button">Добавить</button>
</div>
```

Here is the part of the Code I want to work, but the Button has no effects. Initially I was putting a lot of fonts on a button and input field in css, but then I deleted them and it still doesn't work. By work I mean to print the input of the input field to the console.

Comment: Are you connecting the JS file to the HTML and place it at the end before the body tag?

Comment: can you try changing the id to submit-btn?

Comment: @octaviandd Yes, via <script src="./script.js"></script>

Comment: @vnikonov_63 can you remove the . from the src?

Comment: @NadirLaskar is it because of the naming, because I used different naming in my initial code, for the reasons of the question I chose this one

Comment: @NadirLaskar I checked that the files are connected properly via putting console.log(5) at the top of the script.js file

Comment: @vnikonov_63 There can be lot of reason, what I was thinking maybe you had another button with same id name.

Comment: @NadirLaskar, no it is the only button in the whole HTML file

Comment: Where is the script tag located? You should have it at the end of your body (or at least after your HTML content). If you have it at the beginning, the first two lines will be undefined and you won't be able to attach an event listener. Also, you have "text.Value" but should be "text.value".

Comment: What is *clinking*?

Comment: @DavidFontes - it is at the end of the body tag

Comment: Are you sure your page has only one element with each of the `id` values you are using? `id` **at all times must be unique.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what it was, but you had some weird character in there I think... all I did was removing the `click` and the bracket from the `AddEventListener` function and rewrite it. Strange, I have to admit. Just `textValue.Value` is wrong it needs to be lowercase `textValue.value` otherwise it was completely fine.
**For all reading, this create a snippet and try run with `textValue.value` this was not the mistake. The event listener wasn't set up somehow.**

```js
let submit = document.getElementById("button");
let text = document.getElementById("inputForm");

submit.addEventListener("click", function () {
let textValue = text.value;
console.log("The input is " + textValue)
});
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <h3 id="inputText">Ввод:</h3>
    <input id="inputForm" />
    <button id="button">Добавить</button>
  </div>
```

**Edit:** so I couldn't leave this open, because many of you and myself were confused by which char could it be. I analyzed it in Notepad++ and wanted to see all chars but there was no invisible char like CR or LF. My next thought was the encoding because @vnikonov_63 was writing cyrillic chars inside his html. What I did was transform the code to Windows-1251 (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) and there you can see the result...

```js
submit.addEventListener('СЃlick', function () {
```

Everything is the same but not the `c`. I compared Windows-1251 (cyrillic) and Windows-1250 (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250 Middle European) Encodings and the `c` has the exact same Position. So all of this is just some encoding issue. Surely a `c`which is not really a `c` as javascript expects it, won't set up a eventlistener because javascript doesn't know a event called `СЃlick`. As I am not an expert with encodings i can't explain to you why the `СЃ` shows up as an `c` but i am pretty sure that was the problem.

Comment: Yes Tom. I tested and have the same problem. Good obvervation.

Comment: Thats what I needed. It is difficult to code, when your native language and english have characters, that look the same

Comment: @vnikonov_63 What is the difference between my asnwer below and this answer ? Exactly same

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Tom gave an explanation for why the OP code was not working, which was a hidden character and was not because of the typo in "text.value", that is why it got accepted as the answer.

Comment: @DavidFontes I am not looking for answer accept here. But just wondering what is magical here. Just changing single `''` to double `""` solved the issue ? Just getting my head around to understand more thats all.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Your code is correct and you spotted a mistake but that was not the solution for his problem. He had some character that the browser did not understand (it was invisible I think) and that leads to not setting up the eventlistener. if the .value was the problem the console would have shown "The input is undefined".

Comment: @DavidFontes No probably not. Because `''` is just as valid as `""` I could not spot the character but there had to be some char that made problems.

Comment: @TomSiegel Thanks Tom. I still do not understand what the problem was actually then. I think i shall let go off this one. Its getting confusing to understand what that `invisible ` thing was

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Well, some characters in computer science do not have a visual representation only a numerical value associated, so we (humans) don't see them, but the computer does, and having an invalid character between valid characters may let the code malfunction. I will leave [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) additional information if you want to know more.

Comment: @TomSiegel That was not me saying that :) but yeah, single or double quotes have the same meaning, if properly escaped, they behave exactly the same.

Comment: @TomSiegel Thanks Tom for your valuable input. I am only confused on this `so we (humans) don't see them` - How did you notice it then ? I have never ever seen this kind of behavior for a click function not working because of this.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping see the Edit :)

Comment: @TomSiegel thanks for taking the time so add further explanation. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with the form tag. There is an event for submit when you click the submit button which is type of submit.

code:

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  var text = document.querySelector("#inputForm");
  console.log(text.value);
});
```

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
  <h3 id="inputText">Ввод:</h3>
  <input id="inputForm" />
  <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the Value property. It should be .value.

```
let submit = document.getElementById("button");
let text = document.getElementById("inputForm");

submit.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let textValue = text.value;
  console.log("The input is : " + textValue);
});
```